# Connecting Titan db through Java - throws an exception

Tags: java, titan

I have a java code snippet

```
 TitanGraph g = TitanFactory.open("titan-all-0.4.4/conf/titan-berkeleydb.properties");
```

where `titan-berkeleydb`.properties is the in build config file that comes with Titan db installation.

On execution, it throws an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isNotBlank(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.KCVSConfiguration.<init>(KCVSConfiguration.java:40)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.initialize(Backend.java:273)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1174)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:75)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:29)
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check your classpath for another commons-lang-*.jar. According to the Apache Commons documentation, the isBlank() method is new since 2.0.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29

Titan 0.4.4 ships with commons-lang-2.5.jar in the lib directory. Your original post didn't mention anything else about the runtime environment. I would suspect that if you had, for example, commons-lang-1.0.1.jar on the classpath, it would be picked up before commons-lang-2.5.jar and you would see the error.

Comment: I'm using commons-lang-2.5.jar. I don't have another version of this jar. Is there a way to find out in the code where this exception is thrown from titan? That is where could I get code for KCVSConfiguration.java,  Backend.java, GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java, StandardTitanGraph?

Comment: This isn't a Titan problem. There is a problem in your environment. To reproduce your error, I pulled the titan-all-0.4.4.zip from https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Downloads, and then the commons-lang-1.0.1.jar from here http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/lang/binaries/. If I unzip titan-all-0.4.4.zip, I can open up a TitanGraph from the gremlin.sh console with the berkeley properties. If I copy the commons-lang-1.0.1.jar into the lib directory, it throws the exact exception you are seeing.

Comment: Go through your classpath to ensure you aren't picking up anything unintended. Are you including anything other than TITAN_HOME/lib/* on the classpath?

Comment: Thanks! yes, I had included some unnecessary libraries. When I removed them, it's getting connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a web application with `Tomcat`, you have to add the `jar` file into `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the application (or into $TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder, if you have more webapps using it).

Either create a library with this jar and add it to the project class path.

If you done all this and it still not working, you can change the `jar` extension to `zip` or `rar` and open it to see if the requested classes you need are inside.

Comment: I've done the initial steps you mentioned already. I just confirmed that commons-lang-2.5.jar has the class 'StringUtils' and has the method 'isNotBlank' defined. (for which the exception is thrown)

Comment: Did you import the classes?

Comment: I imported the commons-lang-2.5.jar file in my project and through build config.

Comment: please add some more info about your application architecture